# How can I use Boxplots to find patterns in each box data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, boxplot

I have represented my dataset in Boxplot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fieef.jpg) in order to check if there is patterns in meals consumption within each age group.

What I can see, is that there is a kind of patterns in each age group, without considering the outliers, since they are not widely distributed in the boxes?
I was thinking that the graph shows a slight different pattern in each age group, except for groups 20-29 and 30-39, do you agree?

Any thought on this?

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: How many people are in each age group?  Are the data discrete (eg, are fractional values possible)? What do you mean by "patterns" / what patterns do you have in mind?

Comment: The people in each group is as follows: (42 in 30-39) , (33 in 20-29), (13 in 40-49), (9 in 50-59) and (9 in 18-19). the values are discrete and I meant by patterns is that there is a consistency in the dataset or its predictable. But I think since the data are not equally distributed in the data. there is no consistency and the groups with the highest values have better box plots!

Comment: What, exactly, are the data?  Is it a count of how many meals people eat per timeperiod or something? (>3 would seem weird, though.) If these are counts, you could run a Poisson regression of meals on age group to see if there are significant differences.